# T String When using a reference

Tags: php

I am using this as a reference

```
$jpsupp1 = '<?=$gamesss['jackpot']?>';
```

How can I use this without the 'jackpot' giving me t_string errors?

Comment: Why do you have `<?=` if you're already in PHP mode? That's only used when you're in HTML mode and want to print a PHP variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
$jpsupp1 = $gamesss['jackpot'];
```

You don't need `<?=` when you're already executing PHP code. That's used for embedding PHP in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes

```
$jpsupp1 = "<?=$gamesss['jackpot']?>";
```

or

```
$jpsupp1 = "<?={$gamesss['jackpot']}?>";
```

Depending on what you want to store.

Comment: why would you even need to encapsulate it...?